# New poster - getting downvotes but not sure why

Tags: discussion

I'm getting a few downvotes and no comments on a question and I'm not sure why. It's a politically contentious issue in the US.

Usually when I post on new SE sites and get downvoted it comes with commentary that helps me better gauge the expectations of the community, but this time that doesn't seem to be the case. Any comments on what could be improved on this question would be appreciated:

[Is the election apparatus in Georgia run by Democrats?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/49767/is-the-election-apparatus-in-georgia-run-by-democrats)

I'm also acutely aware that it's a politically tense time, so I took extra care not to insinuate any political leaning or bias in the tone of my question.

Comment: One of the downvotes has just been reversed, and with the question now in HNQ, you're sitting at +4 and counting.

Comment: That's interesting. I haven't materially changed the question. So I take it there's nothing wrong with it then? I suppose the downvotes are understandable given how charged the environment around this is..

Comment: I personally don't see any problems with it, no, and I was honestly a little confused myself to see it sitting at -1 earlier. I will note, however, that commenting on downvotes isn't mandatory, and is in fact actively discouraged by some users, out of fear of retaliation by those they have downvoted. (I'm not at all suggesting you yourself would retaliate in that matter, but believe me, it does happen.)

Comment: If I can be candid, not everything Trump says is interesting, worth investigating, or even meaningful.

Comment: @fredsbend: For better or for worse, he is the President of the United States. His claims are politically significant even if you personally don't find them interesting.

Comment: @Kevin Perhaps you can make that argument, but it has no relevance here, where voting can be and is encouraged to be based on personal interest.

Comment: @fredsbend: In this specific case, I tend to imagine that at least a few of the upvotes on that question were a result of people perceiving the previous downvotes as "unfair." But I agree that you can vote based on whatever you want. I just don't think it's necessarily productive in cases like this.

Comment: On an side, it's a shame that downvoters feel discouraged to comment for fear of reprisal. If that's a real phenomenon, it seems like a bug in the design of the site, as the community would surely benefit from downvoters feeling free to provide critical feedback.

Comment: same thing here with this https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/43868/is-the-infinity-mg10-a-working-generator-that-consumes-no-fuel/49863#49863